# how do you send emails with aws ses and get signals with django-amazon-ses

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, email, amazon-ses

I have followed the setup instructions in django-amazon-ses

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-amazon-ses/1.0.0

But how do I actually send emails using AWS SES with django-amazon-ses ?

I only see signals (pre_send and post_send), but what is the method to actually send out the email with aws ses and also receive signals? Is there further configurations like subject, body, etc ?

Comment: Have you read the readme here: https://github.com/azavea/django-amazon-ses ? You just configure Django to use that backend, and then send email using Django's email utilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy way to do it is to use SES as a SMTP Server.

1. Create [SES Credentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/smtp-credentials.html)
2. Configure [Django settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-EMAIL_HOST) to use SES

   ```
   EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
   EMAIL_HOST = 'email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com'
   EMAIL_PORT = 465
   EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'my_smtp_username'
   EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'my_smtp_password'
   EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
   ```
3. Send email with [email function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/email/) or [EmailMessage](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/email/#emailmessage-objects)

   ```
   from django.core.mail import send_mail
   send_mail(
       'Subject here',
       'Here is the message.',
       'from@example.com',
       ['to@example.com'],
       fail_silently=False,
   )
   ```

Comment: can this get all the signals from ses, like bounce, etc ? django_amazon_ses has that feature. i need to manage those

Comment: No, you didn't mention in your question. Please update your question and include those requirements.